# Broken string in exception?

Tags: c++

I am throwing some parse exceptions. But an exception takes broken string..?

```
//Parse exception
class ParseException : public exception {
public:
    //Constructor
    //Arguments:
    //  Str: Message
    //  Pos: Position
    ParseException(string Str, int Pos) {
        msg = Str;
        pos = Pos;
    }

    //Get what happened(From exception)
    //Returns:
    //  Message with position
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        string str = msg;
        str += " at " + to_string(pos);
        return str.c_str();
    }
private:
    string msg; //Message
    int pos;    //Position
};
```

This is exception class. And I throwed this exception like this:

```
throw ParseException("Mismatched bracket", P.Pos);
```

This exception is thrown and goes to:

```
try {
    Parse(p);
}
catch (ParseException e) { // <<< Here
    cerr << "ParseException: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

And what I get is:

```
ParseException: ▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌
```

Is there a problem with my code? Or problem of Visual Studio(or Compiler)?

Comment: `str` is local to `what()`. It will be destroyed when the function exits. Returning `str.c_str()` yields undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309816/broken-string-in-exception/36310070#comment60243039_36309816), you can't return the `c_str` of a local `string` without creating undefined behavior. It might make sense to store a `string` cache of the `what` value on the exception itself; [the `char*` returned by `what` needs to live as long as the exception object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/what/), so caching on the exception is reasonable.

```
class ParseException : public exception {
public:
    //Constructor
    //Arguments:
    //  Str: Message
    //  Pos: Position
    ParseException(string Str, int Pos) : msg(std::move(Str)), pos(Pos) {}

    //Get what happened(From exception)
    //Returns:
    //  Message with position
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        // Lazily populate what so it's not populated until called
        if (_what.empty()) {
            _what = msg + " at " + to_string(pos);
        }
        return _what.c_str();
    }
private:
    string msg; //Message
    int pos;    //Position
    string _what;
};
```

Alternatively, you compute the value in the constructor so `what` remains `nothrow` compatible (matching the C++ standard library exceptions).